# Recomemded way to select/choose a day of a month (up to 31) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, frontend

Flutter has a showTimePicker and a showDatePicker. But for those who only want to choose a day between 1 and 31 *is there a similar made solution?*
If not there are manny options to build this, *so what is the most adequated* (material widget?)?

In this case, the goal is to select the day of the month at which a monthly recurring payment will provide alerts and notify the missing payments.

Note: It is okay to be 31 if the user wants it to be at the end of each month, since the way I'm implementing is comparing the int of current day with the select day, so no worries about Febreuary and month with 30 days

Comment: there is no such dedicated widget, instead create s simple `GridView` with required number of days

Comment: EIther what pskink said or just use a DropdownButton and add the list options for each day?